# Visual Studio 2015 performance problems in other applications

Tags: windows, xamarin, adobe, visual-studio-2015

there is a weird problem with VS2015 (Enterprise). After installing VS2015 I got massive performance problems in games and all Adobe CC applications.
I experienced this problem in Windows 8.1 Pro and Windows 10 Pro.
I think the problem is not hardware related because there are no problems without VS2015.

About the problem:

1. Installing VS2015 will cause a performance loss of about 50% in games and makes Adobe CC applications lag.
2. Installing the Xamarin 3-rd party tools with the Android SDKs makes everything worse.
3. The CPU and GPU usage seems not to be affected. This is the weirdest part I guess. The CPU and GPU usage does not change but the games/applications just stutter and run really slow.
4. Uninstalling VS2015 does NOT solve the problem. Not even system recovery. I have to reinstall Windows to fix this issue.
5. It does NOT occur after a fresh install of Windows, only after VS2015 is installed.

Has anyone experienced the same problem? Is there any solution to this problem?

Best regards

SOLUTION:
I replaced my processor and now it works just fine. It seems that the **AMD Phenom II x4 955** has serious problems with VS2015.

Comment: Related: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2894215

Comment: Which processor did you replace your Phenom with?